# How to display the value of a variable used in a PL/SQL block in the log file of a batch file? And Arrays?

Tags: variables, batch-file, plsql, getline

Basically I'm using a batch file to run a .sql file on Windows Task Scheduler. The batch file generates a log file that displays all the put_lines. I now want to also see the value assigned to the variable: **v_chks_dm**, but couldn't figure out a way to do it. Tried the get_line statement but failed... Does anyone know how to do it?
thanks!

This is what's in the batch file:

```
echo off
echo ****************************>>C:\output.log

sqlplus userid/password@csdpro @V:\CONDITION_TEST.sql>>C:\output.log
```

Here's the .sql file

```
declare 
  v_chks_dm  number;
  begin
  Select /*+parallel (a,4)*/ count(distinct a.src_table) into v_chks_dm
    from hcr_dm.hcr_dm_fact a;
    dbms_output.put_line('v_chkt_dm value assigned');
--  dbms_output.get_line(v_chks_dm);
  if.... then... else.... end if;
  end;
```

One more question... what if the variable is an array? I have something like this, but got an error says ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count. The number of values in the array usually varies from 0 to 10, but could be more. Thanks!

```
  declare 
  type v_chks_array is varray(10) of varchar2(50);
  arrSRCs v_chks_array;
  begin
  arrSRCs :=v_chks_array();
  arrSRCs.EXTEND(10);
  Select /*+parallel (a,4)*/ distinct a.src_table BULK collect into arrSRCs
    from hcr_dm.hcr_dm_fact a;
  dbms_output.put_line(arrSRCs(10));
  end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dbms_output.put_line('v_chkt_dm value = ' || v_chkt_dm);
```

or, better

```
dbms_output.put_line('v_chkt_dm value = ' || to_char(v_chkt_dm, '<number format>'));
```

You can choose appropriate number formats in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211).

Comment: Well that was easy... Thanks!

Comment: Well, you also should know about functions lpad and rpad, I predict it is next you will want to use :)))

Comment: You can use lpad and rpad functions to format text output.